# Ensemble vs Meta Classifier

Tags: references, definition, ensemble-learning

Are "ensemble" and "Meta Classifier" the same thing?

I see the term "ensemble" being used more frequently - often when talking about combining classifier predictions using majority voting for example, where as meta classifier seems to be different in that it means training a classifier using predictions of a base classifier to create a better (hence the word meta) classifier.

Links to literature would be appreciated.